# Adding margin-left to a div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a lot of divs here and I want to add 55px to all the margin-left not set it to 55px but add it to what is already on there here is some code.

```
$("#AfirstObj,#AsecondObj,#AthirdObj,#AfourthObj, #AfithObj,#AsixthObj,#AseventhObj,#AeightObj,#AnineObj,#AtenthObj,#AeleventhObj,#AtwelveObj,#AthirteenObj,#AfourteenObj,#AfifthteenObj,#AsixteenObj, #AseventeenObj,#AeighteenObj,#AnineteenObj").what do i add here? ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop through them and add `55` to the current `margin-left` value.

```
$("#AfirstObj,#AsecondObj,#AthirdObj,#AfourthObj, #AfithObj,#AsixthObj,#AseventhObj,#AeightObj,#AnineObj,#AtenthObj,#AeleventhObj,#AtwelveObj,#AthirteenObj,#AfourteenObj,#AfifthteenObj,#AsixteenObj, #AseventeenObj,#AeighteenObj,#AnineteenObj").each(function() {
  $(this).css('margin-left', function(i, val) {
    return String(parseInt(val) + 55) + 'px';
  })
});
```

---

Working Example.

```js
$('#one, #two, #three, #four').each(function() {
  $(this).css('margin-left', function(i, val) {
    return String(parseInt(val) + 55) + 'px';
  })
})
```

```css
#one, #two, #three, #four {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tan;
}
#one, #three {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#two, #four {
  margin-left: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `css()` twice: `$(this).css('margin-left', function (i,val) { return val + 55; })` should work just as well, `val` being the current value of the `margin-left` property.

Comment: My console spits out this error when I use that.
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,